# Redshift regexp_replace

Tags: amazon-redshift, regexp-replace

I have a string like:
'start the string {replace this} continue the string {replace this too} and for good measure, continue the string some more'
I need the result to be:
'start the string % continue the string % and for good measure, continue the string some more'

I am trying to replace any/all occurrence(s) of open/close squiggly brackets with % to use in a dynamic SQL statement utilizing the like operator.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the `{replace this}` like strings with `%` you can use a regex replace function like this:

```
with input(txt) as (
    select 'start the string {replace this} continue the string {replace this too} and for good measure, continue the string some more'::varchar
)
select regexp_replace(txt, '\\{[\\w\\s]*\\}', '%') from input;
```

returns

`start the string % continue the string % and for good measure, continue the string some more`

---

But instead of having the described 2 step search where you first replace all template parts with `%` and then do the `LIKE` over that, why not just do a regex search?

```
with input(txt) as (
    select 'start the string {replace this} continue the string {replace this too} and for good measure, continue the string some more'::varchar
)
select txt from input
where
txt ~ 'start the string \\{.*\\} continue the string \\{.*\\} and for good measure, continue the string some more'
```

Comment: thank you very botchniaque, this looks interesting, but i'm having difficulty applying it to the detail of my problem, so here's a bit more. I have table FOO that has text 'Thank You Billy for buying flowers on 20202/01/01', in table BAR I have a text template with template_id 1 and 'Thank You {firstname} for buying {item} on {date}' and i need for the text from FOO to be able to join to BAR and retrieve template_id 1. Not sure if I just made it more confusing, but let me go work with your suggestion, again, much appreciated!

Comment: I was able to use your guidance and apply it to my use case and get it working, thanks so much, I will post the solution once cleaned up a bit!

Comment: If the answer was helpful, you can consider marking is as _accepted_ :)